# contour integration and analytically

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am trying to compute the following contour integration but am quite stuck I have to evaluate it analytically, by extending it to the complex plane and solving an appropriate integral involving a complex variable $z=x+iy$:

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(x^2-4)(x^2+9)} dx $$

and then write a fortran program to evaluate it numerically

Comment: You need to include some formatting on your integral; it makes no sense in its present form.  Take a look at http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: i don't know how to formatting integral ?could any one help me

Comment: I formatted your math. Please let me know if this is what you intended.

Comment: Yes ,that is right ,Thank you